# Creating a probability distribution using Numpy in Python3.6

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I'm trying to create a probability distribution using Numpy in the following way:

```
x = 3
pat = [0.20, 0.30, 1.30]
z = numpy.random.choice(x, p=numpy.ndarray.tolist(numpy.array(pat)/sum(pat)))
```

And this works fine. The problem is that my "population" is evolving and starts at 0, meaning that this may happen:

```
x = 3
pat = [0, 0, 0]
z = numpy.random.choice(x, p=numpy.ndarray.tolist(numpy.array(pat)/sum(pat)))
```

At which point, python is dividing by 0 and returns an error. Is there anyway to create a probability distribution of this kind?

Comment: replace numpy.ndarray.tolist(numpy.array(pat)/sum(pat)) with numpy.ndarray.tolist(numpy.array(pat)/sum(pat)+1e-9).It will make sure that denominator will not be zero but a very very small number. It won't change you answer and not give divide by zero error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one line it will look like this:

```
z = numpy.random.choice(x, p=numpy.ndarray.tolist(numpy.array(pat)/sum(pat))) if any(pat) else numpy.random.choice(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `if/else` for the edge case:

```
if sum(pat) != 0:
    z = numpy.random.choice(x, p=numpy.ndarray.tolist(numpy.array(pat)/sum(pat)))
else:
    z = numpy.random.choice(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using python function to find the probability distribution where
Sum(pijlog(pin) - sum(pi(log(pi) -sum(on(log(pj))

Comment: Please use code fences to display code as such. Thank you! 

Like this

Using python function to find the probability distribution where

``
Sum(pijlog(pin) - sum(pi(log(pi) -sum(on(log(pj))
``